# Using preg_split on an empty string

Tags: php, preg-split

In PHP, when I run the following command:

```
$text = "";
$arr = preg_split('/,/', $text, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($arr);
```

I get the following array with a single empty element:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
```

Yet, if I run it with -1 as the limit:

```
$text = "";
$arr = preg_split('/,/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($arr);
```

I get a completely empty array:

```
Array
(
)
```

Why is this the case? According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) -1 is the default value so I would expect the results to be the same in both cases.

Comment: Have you tried to count the characters with `strlen()` function?

Comment: PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
    If this flag is set, only non-empty pieces will be returned by preg_split(). 
so its giving onli non emty value so use another like "PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> preg_split($pattern , $subject [, int $limit = -1     [, int $flags = 0 ]] )
> preg_split('/,/'    , $text     , PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY                      );
> ```

The third parameter is the limit, `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY == 1`, when you pass `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` as the third argument you're telling it the limit is 1 - you're **not** passing it in as a flag.

Comment: So in short: Passed the constant as wrong argument = Empty elements are allowed